Azure Container access via Python SDK fails with AuthorizationPermissionMismatch but I am owner
I'm trying to list the blobs in a container in Azure Storage in a python script using the Azure SDK.
However, I'm getting the error "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch".
This surprises me, because through the GUI I can list the contents just like that. I am the owner of the container:

and I think that I got all the code right:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = ContainerClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        account_url="https://satestblobaccess.blob.core.windows.net",
        container_name="stcnt-test-blob-access"
    )

    blob_names = client.list_blob_names()
    print([b for b in blob_names])

I'm running this in a powershell while I am logged in as myself and the SDK seems to pick up my identity just fine.
So I would expect to get a list of the blob names.
Instead I get the AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error.
It would be great if someone could point out to me how to fix this ...
The output is this (sorry for the mangle, I can't get it to display the line breaks that I see in the powershell output window):

[INFO azure.identity._credentials.environment] No environment configuration found.
INFO:azure.identity._credentials.environment:No environment configuration found.
[INFO azure.identity._credentials.managed_identity] ManagedIdentityCredential will use IMDS
INFO:azure.identity._credentials.managed_identity:ManagedIdentityCredential will use IMDS
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request URL: 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=REDACTED&resource=REDACTED'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.15.0 Python/3.10.13 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
No body was attached to the request
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254:80
[INFO azure.identity._credentials.chained] DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from AzureCliCredential
INFO:azure.identity._credentials.chained:DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from AzureCliCredential
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request URL: 'https://satestblobaccess.blob.core.windows.net/stcnt-test-blob-access?restype=REDACTED&comp=REDACTED'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
'Accept': 'application/xml'
'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.19.0 Python/3.10.13 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
'x-ms-client-request-id': 'f729fa05-19dd-11ef-ae9a-a434d95f5cd9'
'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): satestblobaccess.blob.core.windows.net:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://satestblobaccess.blob.core.windows.net:443 "GET /stcnt-test-blob-access?restype=container&comp=list HTTP/1.1" 403 279
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Response status: 403
Response headers:
'Content-Length': '279'
'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
'x-ms-request-id': 'fc138e07-a01e-0062-75ea-ad615a000000'
'x-ms-client-request-id': 'f729fa05-19dd-11ef-ae9a-a434d95f5cd9'
'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
'x-ms-error-code': 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch'
'Date': 'Fri, 24 May 2024 14:57:44 GMT'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yrdeb\PycharmProjects\test_blob_access_man_ident\main.py", line 30, in 
File "C:\Users\yrdeb\PycharmProjects\test_blob_access_man_ident\main.py", line 30, in 
print([b for b in blob_names])
File "C:\Users\yrdeb.conda\envs\env3106\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 123, in next
return next(self._page_iterator)
File "C:\Users\yrdeb.conda\envs\env3106\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 75, in next
self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
File "C:\Users\yrdeb.conda\envs\env3106\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_list_blobs_helper.py", line 179, in _get_next_cb
process_storage_error(error)
File "C:\Users\yrdeb.conda\envs\env3106\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_shared\response_handlers.py", line 184, in process_storage_error
exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec
File "", line 1, in 
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:fc138e07-a01e-0062-75ea-ad615a000000
Time:2024-05-24T14:57:44.6182291Z
Content: AuthorizationPermissionMismatchThis request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:fc138e07-a01e-0062-75ea-ad615a000000
Time:2024-05-24T14:57:44.6182291Z


To access data inside a container, you need to assign yourself “Storage Blob Data Contributor” role.

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#resource-scope you need Storage Blob Data Contributor role.


AuthorizationPermissionMismatch This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId: fc138e07-a01e-0062-75ea-ad615a000000 Time: 2024-05-24T14:57:44.6182291Z

The above error occurs when you don't have proper permission to access the Azure Blob Storage.
According to this MS-Document,
To access the blob inside the container, you need to assign yourself or the user Storage Blob Data Contributor role.
In my environment, I assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor to the particular container in the portal.
Portal:

Now, after assigning the role, I executed the same code in my environment. It worked successfully.
Code
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = ContainerClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        account_url="https://venkat456.blob.core.windows.net",
        container_name="test"
    )

    blob_names = client.list_blob_names()
    print([b for b in blob_names])

Output:
['Adobe Scan 10-Apr-2024.pdf', 'document.PDF', 'gnupg-2.4.5.tar.bz2.sig', 'industry.csv.gpg', 'sample2.ps1']



This works, thank you! You know, I find this a bit disturbing, though. You see, when in the GUI, I can access the container list without that role. I'd expect to be able to have the same access when going through the CLI or SDK (logged-in as the same identity), so it never occurred to me I needed more permissions :) ... anyway, all good now.
